# Saving the result of a Spark Streaming application

Tags: spark-streaming

I'm coding a Spark Streaming Application and I need to save the updated model, so I did as follows:

```
data.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  model = model.update(rdd) 
  rdd.context.parallelize(model.nodes).saveAsTextFile("target/model")
                         //model.nodes is an Array[Vector]
}
```

The problem is that I get this error (since it's a loop):

```
Output directory file "target/model" already exists
```

Could someone have an idea to solve this problem ?! thanks

Comment: add an integer value that you can increment with each loop and append it to the file name?

Comment: @S O - yes it is an option, but I only want to save the last model (with the idea of an integer value, it'll create a lot of files !!)

Comment: you could test the upper boundary of the model.nodes array and if the increment integer = that boundary then save?

Comment: I couldn't because it is supposed to be an infinite stream !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark