# Spark MLLib unable to write out to S3 : path already exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have data in a S3 bucket in directory `/data/vw/`. Each line is of the form:

`| abc:2 def:1 ghi:3 ...`

I want to convert it to the following format:

`abc abc def ghi ghi ghi`

The new converted lines should go to S3 in directory `/data/spark`

Basically, repeat each string the number of times that follows the colon. I am trying to convert a VW LDA input file to a corresponding file for consumption by Spark's LDA library.

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Vw2SparkLdaFormatConverter {

  def repeater(s: String): String = {
      val ssplit = s.split(':')
        (ssplit(0) + ' ')  * ssplit(1).toInt
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val inputPath = args(0)
      val outputPath = args(1)

      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FormatConverter")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val vwdata = sc.textFile(inputPath)
      val sparkdata = vwdata.map(s => s.trim().split(' ').map(repeater).mkString)

      val coalescedSparkData = sparkdata.coalesce(100)
      coalescedSparkData.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)

      sc.stop()
  }
}
```

When I run this (as a Spark EMR job in AWS), the step fails with exception:

```
18/01/20 00:16:28 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory s3a://mybucket/data/spark already exists
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory s3a://mybucket/data/spark already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at ...
```

The code is run as:

```
spark-submit --class Vw2SparkLdaFormatConverter --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true --executor-memory 4g s3a://mybucket/scripts/myscalajar.jar s3a://mybucket/data/vw s3a://mybucket/data/spark
```

I have tried specifying new output paths (`/data/spark1` etc), ensuring that it does not exist before the step is run. Even then it is not working.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Scala and Spark so I might be overlooking something here.

Comment: BTW, the job does create the directory `/data/spark` in S3 (and I also see a `_temporary` in there), but the job fails a few moments after that.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert to a dataframe and then save with overwrite enabled.

```
coalescedSparkData.toDF.write.mode('overwrite').csv(outputPath)
```

Or if you insist on using RDD methods, you can do as described [already in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193839/4540147)

Comment: But why is it failing in the first place?

Comment: The above snippet worked, although since I still don't know the issue with the original code, I am not marking this as a solution (but upvoted your answer). Thanks.