# How to overwrite the rdd saveAsPickleFile(path) if file already exist in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

How to overwrite 
RDD output objects any existing path when we are saving time.

test1:

```
975078|56691|2.000|20171001_926_570_1322
975078|42993|1.690|20171001_926_570_1322
975078|46462|2.000|20171001_926_570_1322
975078|87815|1.000|20171001_926_570_1322

rdd=sc.textFile('/home/administrator/work/test1').map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:4]).map( lambda r: Row( user_code = r[0],item_code = r[1],qty = float(r[2])))
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsPickleFile("/home/administrator/work/foobar_seq1")
```

The first time it is saving properly. now again I removed one line from the input 
    file and saving RDD same location, it show file has existed.

```
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsPickleFile("/home/administrator/work/foobar_seq1")
```

For example, in dataframe we can overwrite existing path.

```
df.coalesce(1).write().overwrite().save(path)
```

If I am doing same on RDD object getting an error.

```
rdd.coalesce(1).write().overwrite().saveAsPickleFile(path)
```

please help me on this

Comment: `RDD` doesn't have a write method. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I have changed my question.ya your right RDD doesn't have write method ,is there any method in RDD which is equals to write method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite the output directory in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can save RDD files like below
***Note*** (code is in scala but logic should be same for python as well) i am using 2.3.0 spark version.

```
  val sconf = new SparkConf().set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "False").setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test")
  val scontext = new SparkContext(sconf)
  val lines = scontext.textFile("s${filePath}", 1)
    println(lines.first)
    lines.saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\sample2")
```

or if ur working with DataFrame then use

```
DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path.parquet)
```

or for more info please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Hi Raj  Thanks for reply, "DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path.parquet")" for data frame but i want save RDD object.

Comment: ok i have provided older version that is for rdd plz try that

Comment: i will try,can you please provided new version huh?

Comment: pyspark 2.2 version

Comment: ok for 2.2 version are u working with sparkContext or SparkSession if sparkContext then this will work sparkconf =  SparkConf().setAppName("someName").set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", False)
sparkcontext = SparkContext(conf = sparkconf),

Comment: spark SparkSession I am using

Answer (score 0):

While, the rdd without write mode, and you can convert rdd to df , using df overwrite mode. As follows:

```
df.coalesce(1).toDF().map(lambda x: (x,)).write.csv(path=yourpath, mode='overwrite')
```