# How to automatically overwrite files in output_path with rdd.saveAsPickleFile(output_path)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, pickle, overwrite

Writing files via rdd.saveAsPickleFile(output_path) fails if the directory already exists. While that is a good thing to avoid accidental file deletion, I was wondering if there was an option to explicitly overwrite the folder/the files? Similarly to dataframes:

> df.write.mode('overwrite').format('json').save(output_path)

Note: the following two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528893/how-to-overwrite-the-rdd-saveaspicklefilepath-if-file-already-exist-in-pyspark) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark) have asked this before but not received explicit answers.

Comment: And if you're still in doubt [How to set hadoop configuration values from pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27033823/8371915)

Comment: In that question, it is suggested to convert to dataframes. As opposed to that, I would like to know if it is possible to overwrite the output directly from rdd.saveAsPickleFile(output_path)

Comment: Accepted answer specifically describes how to overwrite with legacy API. You won't get more explicit answer than that.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you would like to explicitly delete the folder where your pickle file is created each time you run your script. You could delete the directory at `output_path` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840586/5671433 before you call

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format('json').save(output_path)
```

Comment: The question was about to overwrite an **RDD**, not **Dataframe**.

Comment: The question was about to overwrite an RDD, not Dataframe