# Scala Spark - Overwrite parquet File on HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to append the data frame to existing parquet file found option to have the saveMode to append. But when I was trying to append it throws the error it was not the directory.

```
data.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("/user/root/AppendTest");

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/root/AppendTest":root:root:-rw-r--r-- (Ancestor /user/root/AppendTest is not a directory).
```

P.S: While was creating the new file it was generated to the folder and then I have renamed to the desired file.

I have checked [How to overwrite the output directory in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark) but that doesn't solve my problem here. I have tried the ways mentioned in the above questions(issue mentioned is also different).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite the output directory in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark)

Comment: @Emest, I have checked that question but that issue was diffrent

Comment: The file you try to access can only be changed by root so you have to run your spark job as root or change the permission to this file