# Dataproc: Errors when reading and writing data from BigQuery using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read some BigQuery data, (ID: `my-project.mydatabase.mytable` [original names protected]) from a user-managed Jupyter Notebook instance, inside [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc?hl=es) Workbench. What I am trying is inspired in [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/bigquery-connector-spark-example?hl=en#submit_a_pyspark_wordcount_batch_workload), and more specifically, the code is (please read some additional comments, on the code itself):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType, StringType
from google.cloud import bigquery

# UPDATE (2022-08-10): BQ conector added
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SpacyOverPySpark') \
                    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.24.2') \
                    .getOrCreate()

# ------------------ IMPORTING DATA FROM BIG QUERY --------------------------

# UPDATE (2022-08-10): This line now runs...
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', 'my-project.mydatabase.mytable').load()

# But imports the whole table, which could become expensive and not optimal
print("DataFrame shape: ", (df.count(), len(df.columns)) # 109M records & 9 columns; just need 1M records and one column: "posting"

# I tried the following, BUT with NO success:
# sql = """
# SELECT `posting`
# FROM `mentor-pilot-project.indeed.indeed-data-clean`
# LIMIT 1000000
# """
# df = spark.read.format("bigquery").load(sql)
# print("DataFrame shape: ", (df.count(), len(df.columns)))

# ------- CONTINGENCY PLAN: IMPORTING DATA FROM CLOUD STORAGE ---------------

# This section WORKS (just to enable the following sections)
# HINT: This dataframe contains 1M rows of text, under a single column: "posting"
df = spark.read.csv("gs://hidden_bucket/1M_samples.csv", header=True)

# ---------------------- EXAMPLE CUSTOM PROCESSING --------------------------

# Example Python UDF Python
def split_text(text:str) -> list:
    return text.split()

# Turning Python UDF into Spark UDF
textsplitUDF = udf(lambda z: split_text(z), ArrayType(StringType()))

# "Applying" a UDF on a Spark Dataframe (THIS WORKS OK)
df.withColumn("posting_split", textsplitUDF(col("posting")))

# ------------------ EXPORTING DATA TO BIG QUERY ----------------------------

# UPDATE (2022-08-10) The code causing the error:

# df.write.format('bigquery') \
#   .option('table', 'wordcount_dataset.wordcount_output') \
#   .save()

# has been replace by a code that successfully stores data in BQ:

df.write \
  .format('bigquery') \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "my_temp_bucket_name") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save("my-project.mynewdatabase.mytable")
```

When reading data from BigQuery, using a SQL query, the error triggered is:

```bash
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o195.load.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataset' not parsed or provided.
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.provideSparkBigQueryConfig(SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.java:65)
  while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig

1 error
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1097)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1131)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelationInternal(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:75)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataset' not parsed or provided.
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryUtil.lambda$parseTableId$2(BigQueryUtil.java:153)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryUtil.parseTableId(BigQueryUtil.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.from(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:237)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.provideSparkBigQueryConfig(SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.java:67)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorModule$$FastClassByGuice$$db983008.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1094)
    ... 18 more
```

When writing data to BigQuery, the error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o167.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

**UPDATE:** (2022-09-10) The error when writing data to BigQuery has been solved, please refer to the code above, as well as the comment section below.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add BQ connector when creating the cluster?

Comment: Did you add the BQ connector jar in the dataproc?

Comment: Hello @Dagang. I have updated the enunciate, your suggestion worked, but opened a couple of derived questions. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Subash . I have updated the enunciate, your suggestion worked, but opened a couple of derived questions. Thanks.

Comment: Seems there is a typo in `my-project:mydatabase.mytable`, I think it should be `my-project.mydatabase.mytable`

Comment: Thanks @Dagang, typo has been corrected.

Comment: Do you have table `wordcount_dataset.wordcount_output` in your project?

Comment: I just did it @Dagang. I thought however that the writing line of code was gonna take care of creating both the dataset as the table, which seems not to be the case (SHould I always create them beforehand then?) Plus, I have updated the error triggered (still triggers one). Thanks

Comment: Try add `.mode("overwrite")` when saving. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033823/how-to-overwrite-the-output-directory-in-spark

Comment: Done @Dagang. Triggers error `'Either temporary or persistent GCS bucket must be set'`. BTW, in the link you provided, there were lots of answers, the one I used was `df.write.mode("overwrite").format('bigquery').option('table', 'my-project.test_output_data.test_output_table').save()` (amongst others). Would be nice to have a "better / correct" implementation suggested. Thanks

Comment: It is documented here https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#writing-data-to-bigquery, you can do either direct or indirect write which requires you set a bucket.

Comment: Also in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/bigquery-connector-spark-example?hl=en#submit_a_pyspark_wordcount_batch_workload), it has `spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)`.

Comment: Thanks @Dagang. I have succeeded when writing data to BigQuery (I have updated to code). Any ideas about why I cannot run the SQL query?

Comment: You need to add some Spark properties `spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")` and `spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")` https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#reading-data-from-a-bigquery-query

Comment: I added an answer, could you accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Dagang, I have included some modification requests in your answer. Let's improve it there, thks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key points found during the discussion:

1. Add the BigQuery connector as a dependency through `spark.jars=<gcs-uri>` or `spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_<scala-version>:<version>`.
2. Specify the correct table name in `<project>.<dataset>.<table>` format.
3. The default mode for dataframe writer is `errorifexists`. When writing to a non-existent table, the dataset must exist, the table will be created automatically. When writing to an existing table, mode needs to be set as `"append"` or `"overwrite"` in `df.write.mode(<mode>)...save()`.
4. When writing to a BQ table, do either

   a)  direct write (supported since [0.26.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.spark/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12/0.26.0))

   ```
   df.write \
     .format("bigquery") \
     .option("writeMethod", "direct") \
     .save("dataset.table")
   ```

   b) or indirect write

   ```
   df.write \
     .format("bigquery") \
     .option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket") \
     .save("dataset.table")
   ```

   See this [doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#writing-data-to-bigquery).
5. When reading from BigQuery through a SQL query, add mandatory properties `viewsEnabled=true` and `materializationDataset=<dataset>`:

   ```
   spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
   spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")

   sql = """
     SELECT tag, COUNT(*) c
     FROM (
       SELECT SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
       FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
       WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)>=2014
     ), UNNEST(tags) tag
     GROUP BY 1
     ORDER BY 2 DESC
     LIMIT 10
     """
   df = spark.read.format("bigquery").load(sql)
   df.show()
   ```

   See this [doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#reading-data-from-a-bigquery-query).

Comment: I'd appreciate some additions on your answer before accepting it. For "3", it's important to mention that whatever the destination table ID is, it must exist ==> beforehand <== in BQ, otherwise it won't work (at least that's my experience from this case). For "4a", any explanation as to why "direct write" never worked in the experiments?

Comment: Sounds good. I updated #3, actually the table doesn't have to exist, the dataset does. What error did you see with direct write?

Comment: Regarding direct write, I just learned that it is added since 0.26.0, the doc needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hello @Dagang, thanks for the input. I will accept the answer now.